# how to display the ascii code on the Edittext when a string is entered by the user

Tags: java

I am able to display the code of only the last alphabet of a string and not of the whole string. eg-if i enter "a", then it is showing 65, but if i enter "ab", then it is showing 66. I want to display both 65 and 66.

```
String a = tf1.getText();
    byte b[]=a.getBytes();
    char ch[]=a.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
    tf2.setText(String.valueOf(b[i]));
    }
```

Comment: You overwrite your tf2 each time, when you put the next char. Change this, so you add the next ASCII-code.

Comment: @IQV - I know it is being overriden, but exactly what changes should i made to stop it and display code for all the characters at once.

Comment: @Rohan set the value to a String which contains all the numbers you want.

Comment: @Rohan What type is your tf2?

Comment: @IQV tf2 is TextArea

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to get the input from user

Comment: I recommend the answer of Vijay. Instead of the space you could insert a newline, so you get each number in a new row of the `TextArea`.

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch the existing value from textbox and concat new value and update it again to textbox.

Change the `tf2.setText(String.valueOf(b[i]));` to

`tf2.setText( tf2.getText()+" "+String.valueOf(b[i]));`

Comment: I suggest an additional space: `tf2.setText(tf2.getText()+" "+String.valueOf(b[i]));`

Answer (score 0):

The code `tf2.setText(String.valueOf(b[i]));` will always set the text to a single char value. You should concatenate the values if you wish to display all the character codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text to a String which has all the values you want.

```
String a = tf1.getText();
// take all the chars as int values and join them together with a space between.
String ascii = s.chars().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
tf2.setText(ascii);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
st1=tf1.getText();
char arr[] = st1.toCharArray();
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    iValue =(int)arr[i];
    sb.append(iValue+",");
}
tf2.setText(""+sb);
```